# select all html elements based on rel value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html elements in my code like this

```
<div rel="test1">item1</div>
<div rel="test1">item2</div>
<div rel="test1">item3</div>
<div rel="test2">item4</div>
<div rel="test2">item5</div>
```

and I need a way to select all the divs that use `rel="test1"` and add a class to them
how can I do this with `jQuery`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('div[rel=\'test1\']')
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

You can then add a class with `.addClass()`.  http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: You don't need to escape the `'` you can use `"` or omit it. the quotes must be used for two words value.

Comment: @gdoron, It's a matter of preference.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Is this answer somehow incorrect?  I doubt it.

Comment: Would you say the same thing with this: `'it\'s time your\'s friend get it\'s thing...'` or would you use: `"it's time your's friend get it's thing..."` ?

Comment: @gdoron, Yes, my preference would be to use single quotes there as well.  You are more than welcome to prefer double quotes.

Comment: May I ask why won't you use the double quotes?

Comment: I prefer to express string literals consistently with single quotes.  Whether you use single or double, there are still characters that must be escaped.  Many times such strings will contain HTML with double quotes for parameters.  For what I do, using single quotes means less escaping.  No matter what you do, you should be consistent.

Answer (score 4):

```
​$('div[rel="test1"]')​.addClass("myClass");​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mHHMk/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div[rel="test1"]').addClass('fooClass');
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcEzG/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("div[rel='test1']").addClass("newClass");       
});
```

working sample http://jsfiddle.net/4WEBk/13/

Comment: Though it's true, you didn't show the `addClass` bit. :) might be good idea to add it to your answer.

Comment: I just showed how to access the items with that purticular selection. Found out now that he wants to add class as well. Thanks Guys for pointing out. I updated.